# Unable to pull data from JSON file in factory AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I have a Json file in following format:
name of json file is **discover.json** and path is **json-files/discover.json**

```
    {"data": [
{"username": "aky123", 
    "name": "ajay"}, 
    {"username": "sky123",
     "name": "sanjay"}
    ]}
```

my factory is:

```
var myAppServices=angular.module('myAppServices',['ngResource']);

myAppServices.factory('ProfileData',['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/discover/:username.json', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET' , params: {username: 'json-files/discover' }, isArray: true }
    });
}]);
```

App.js :

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/discover', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home-page.html',
        controller: 'ProfileListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/discover/:username', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/profile-detail.html',
        controller: 'ProfileDetailCtrl'
      })
```

and in controller:

```
myAppControllers.controller('ProfileListCtrl',['$scope', 'ProfileData', '$timeout', function($scope, ProfileData, $timeout) {
        $scope.profile=ProfileData.query();
    console.log($scope.profile);
}]);
```

$scope.profile is not able to pull data from JSON file, I am not able to understand my mistake here so please help me..

Comment: _"name of json file is discover.json"_ if the filename is `discover.json` then why are you using `'/discover/:username.json'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works in my localhost

```
//Service.js
myAppServices.factory('ProfileData',['$resource', function($resource){
return $resource('/discover/:username.json', {},{
'query': {method: 'GET',{}, isArray: false }
});
}]);
//Controller.js
var promise = ProfileData.query();
promise.$promise.then(function(response) {
$scope.data = response.data;
});
//view.html
<li ng-repeat="name in data">
    {{name.username}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not valid json

valid json is:

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "username": "aky123",
        "name": "ajay"
    }, {
        "username": "sky123",
        "name": "sanjay"
    }]
}
```

Comment: To add to this, when debugging anything with a JSON return, put your JSON into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for a quick smoke-test.

Comment: @Mike88 I corrected my Json format but still not able to pull data. 
I think there are some error in service.js , if u will help me in that section then its great. :)